# I try to access the element i am getting Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //a[@class='custom-icon'])

Tags: protractor

Pasting HTML tag for the same. Please check in comment.

Its a side (nav-bar) which I am trying to access using protractor.
/* */

I tried using the xpath, class name other cssselector but all the time I keep getting the error - Not able to locate the element.

Comment: /*<a _ngcontent-mii-c1="" class="custom-icon"><i _ngcontent-mii-c1="" class="fa fa-gavel"></i><span _ngcontent-mii-c1="" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a> */

Comment: add your code also